# Github Pages Jekyll posts not updating

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll blog running on github pages. I have updated it once and it worked. I just added a second post, it worked when I serve it locally, but when I push it to github, it doesnt show the second blog post on the github page. Even if the markdown file appear in the _post directory.

here is my repo: https://github.com/nrkfeller/mini_cap_blog

Any idea why that is?

Comment: It can take some time for GitHub Pages to rebuild after a push. How long have you waited?

Comment: yes It has been 3 hours now, still no update

Comment: Did you get any warning in your email inbox like page build failed? I have check your feed URL, and it's seems it's not updated till.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there's something wrong here at your `_config.yml` file:

```
baseurl: /mini_cap_blog # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "http://nrkfeller.github.io/mini_cap_blog/#" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
```

Replace for this:

```
baseurl: /mini_cap_blog/ 
url: http://nrkfeller.github.io
```

Let me know if this works, yeah?

Comment: **Note:** These days GitHub is secure so rather than `http://` we use `https://`.